# Programmatically uncheck all checkboxes in web form

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_to_cart', function(){


    var product_id = $(this).attr("id");


    var product_name = $('#name'+product_id+'').val();
    var product_price = $('#price'+product_id+'').val();
    var product_quantity = $('#quantity'+product_id).val();
    



    var checked_boxes = $(".opcion_cbox");

    $(".opcion_cbox:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        

        var rowid = $(this).data('rowid');

        var nombre = $(this).data('nombre');
        product_name = product_name.concat(" (+ ",nombre,")");
        var precio = $(this).data('precio');
        var precio_opcion = $(this).data('precio')*product_quantity ;
        product_price = parseFloat(product_price)+parseFloat(precio_opcion);
        product_price = product_price.toFixed(2);
        


    })
```

I would like to force all checkboxes in the web form to be unchecked just after function `$(".opcion_cbox:checkbox:checked").each(function()` is completely executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your .each loop since it seems you're already iterating through each checked checkbox:

`$(this).prop("checked", false);`